# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, material-table

What I'm trying to do is pull data from an `API` and display it in a table using the [material-table library](https://material-table.com). I believe it is me who am not managing to manipulate objects and arrays in the correct way.

My api returns this response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "field01": 1,
      "field02": 1,
      "field03": false,
      "people": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
      },
       "id": 8,
       "field01": 2,
       "field02": 2,
       "field03": false,
       "people": {
         "id": 2
         "name": "Mattew"
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

Code that I use to pull the data from the `api`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getValues = async () => {
    await api.get("/myrequest")
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data.data);

      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

The table I created using the `material-table`:

```
<MaterialTable
            columns={[
              { title: 'Field 01', field: 'field01' },
              { title: 'Field 02', field: 'field02' },
              { title: 'Field 03', field: 'field03' },
              { title: 'Field 04',field: 'people.name' },
            ]}
            data={data}
            title="My table"
          />
```

Looking at the documentation I noticed this: *Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

I believe the error is because my api returns an array and the table does not recognize.

But I still haven't been able to do that. And the way I did it returns the following error:
***Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` supplied to `MaterialTable`***

Comment: Well, try: `response.data.data`.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli I did what I said and it caused me another error. I believe it is because the api returns an object within the array.

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Well I think that the package you are using does not support nested objects. You can  change package or create an adapter that make you array flat.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli Could you help me create this adapter? I'm really new to this and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Check the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the package you are using seems to not be able to handle nested objects so you have two options:

- consider using another package like, for example, `react-table`

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table

- create an adapter to have an array with flat objects

```
const adapter = data => data.map(item => (
    {
        id: item.id,
        field01: item.field01,
        field02: item.field02,
        field03: item.field03,
        name: item.people.name,
    }
));
```

Then in you component

```
<MaterialTable
    columns={[
        { title: 'Field 01', field: 'field01' },
        { title: 'Field 02', field: 'field02' },
        { title: 'Field 03', field: 'field03' },
        { title: 'Field 04',field: 'name' },
    ]}
    data={adapter(data)}
    title="My table"
/>
```

Note:

You should use this field to access your data

```
response.data.data
```

Since, as you wrote, `response.data` has an additional field `data` that contains your array of objects.

Comment: Where am I going to call the constant adapter?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!